# Do you think closing of questions on SO is little overzealous?

Tags: discussion

I  have seen many good questions are closed for reasons such as not-a-good-question. Questions for which we do not have concrete answer, may be because we don't have the right answer, have right to live. May be we will get answer for them in future, when sufficient minds have probed the questions. Many of my questions are victims, btw.
The point I am trying to make is, closing of questions, IMHO, is little overzealous on SO.

Someone please  tell me reasoning beyond the official terse on verge of curt lines of explanation?

Comment: @Ajeet: the number of upvotes on your questions doesn't change the amount of close votes necessary to close them - it's five (the first time) regardless of whether it got no upvotes at all or 100.

Comment: Ajeet, **don't** ask for your question to be upvoted. **Ever.**

Comment: Ajeet, as has been mentioned before (but you may not of seen it), up/down voting on Meta is slightly different to the other sites - it usually means agree or disagree, it doesn't necessarily mean you've got a bad question. If your question remained at zero it would mean either you had no votes, or equal numbers of up/down votes which means your audience is split 50/50. I hope that all makes sense to you.

Comment: Maybe I am really not getting it. So those who down-vote r thinking they are just saying "No SO closers are not overzealous"  ?

Comment: Best case is to take seriously the close reason, edit the question to clarify and fix the problems with it, then flag for reopening.

Answer (score 16):

Let's start with the specifics of your case:

- Two of your questions are closed as *exact duplicate*. I'm not going to dwell on this one—basically, it just means to click on the link at the top of your question to get your answer because it's been asked before. I presume this isn't what you're concerned with.
- [simulate dice with fair coin flip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087419/simulate-dice-with-fair-coin-flip) is a **math** question, not a programming one, and is thus unsuitable for Stack Overflow.
- [Write a C++ program to generate random distribution between 0 to 5 given rand1() which returns 0 or 1 at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127694/write-a-c-program-to-generate-random-distribution-between-0-to-5-given-rand1) doesn't seem to meet this criteria from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> You should only ask **practical**, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058180/max-range-in-array-with-startrange-endrange is just asking for an entire algorithm. Sorry, but we have to see some effort put into the question.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278920/design-question-meta-answer is best answered with the close reason attached:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit **opinion**, debate, arguments, polling, or **extended discussion**.

- [Can someone explain me "Design for self" , "Design by copy", and "Design by research" terminologies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309180/can-someone-explain-me-design-for-self-design-by-copy-and-design-by-resea) isn't a question about **code**, and is thus off-topic.

Speaking with regards to the general case, I don't think that SO is "overzealous" in closing questions. SO gets a lot of questions per day, and it has to establish strict boundaries on what it can and cannot accept to maintain a high standard of quality. There are a lot of other [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), however, and some of your questions may fall within the scope of existing sites.

Comment: I answered the math question in a comment, but that was ignored.  He's not even trying.

Comment: @Matthew Read : I reworded the question and a similar answer was accepted by me. I can't accept your answer in comment, I couldnt help.   Sorry about that.

Comment: @Ajeet Apologies, then -- from the comments it looked like you had missed it due to wanting to argue :P my bad.

Answer (score 13):

> Do you think closing of questions on SO is little overzealous?

No.

Comment: Close early, close often.

Comment: I'm closing at nine today, so you'd better wait until after that.